# Error while inputting EEPROM.read() and EEPROM.write()

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, atmega328, eeprom

I am trying to store data in ATmega328 (Arduino Uno) using the following code using tinkercad:

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

void setup() {
  int addr, data=1;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for (addr=0; addr<1023; addr++) {
    EEPROM.write(addr, data);
  }
  for (addr=0; addr<1023 ; addr++) {
    Serial.print(EEPROM.read(addr), DEC);
  }
}
```

When I simulate the code in the tinkercad, then i get the following error:

```
In function `main':
43: undefined reference to `loop'
 error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me where is the error in my code. I am not able to understand the error source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at any Arduino IDE example programs?

They all have a `setup()` and `loop()` function.

Apparently, Tinkercad is missing the `loop()` function in your code.

You can solve the issue by adding an empty `void loop() { }` after your `void setup() { ... }` code.

Comment: Thank you, now the code works. But I have a question in this code why there is use of the empty void loop() because it executes infinitely. It may be a silly question, I am a beginner to Arduino programming. But please tell what is the significance of empty void loop() in this code?

Comment: In most projects, Arduino code does not just execute once, but runs in a continuous loop, for example to service button presses, display data, take sensor measurements and act on them. The creators of the Arduino IDE have made the loop() function a standard part of every Arduino program to facilitate this. It's not part of standard C++. In your case your program just executes once and the loop() function does not have any significance. It's just doing nothing in a "controlled" way (continuous loop) and waiting for a reset.